# French character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I have a script.js file linking in the head of a HTML page (meta: utf-8)

French characters inside the HTML itself are displayed correctly, but those inside the script.js are not:

`$('#count_fr').html("entrées")` is displayed as `entr[]es` in browser.

Here is how I point to the js file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

I tried

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

but no luck.

Comment: Your .js file is probably not encoded as utf-8.  You can check with a tool like Notepad++, which tells you the file encoding in the lower-right side.  (If you can't be bothered, try changing `charset` to `iso-8859-1` and if it works, you know that's the problem.)

Comment: It does work find http://jsfiddle.net/3Z3CT/

Comment: Make sure you save as UTF-8, and ***do not put a BOM in the file***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the script file is not saved as UTF-8.
You can verify it by using the `file` command on UNIX like systems, or by opening your text editor and looking for a menu command to change the encoding.

Comment: Thanks, by saving the file as "UTF-8 without BOM" it works. But what is the difference between this and specifying the charset in HTML? `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: By specifying the charset at script tag level you are forcing the browser to *interpret* the script as UTF-8, *regardless of how it has been saved*. If it doesn't match the encoding of the file (= the actual representation of the characters), it will not display text properly.

Comment: Specifying the charset in HTML is probably irrelevant, browsers ignore it (they look at the HTTP headers or make a guess). I don’t see any reason *not* to use the BOM, since the BOM is (even in UTF-8) a potentially useful indicator of encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to use Unicode directly for French characters in Javascript files. It works perfectly for me. e.g. \u00fb for û.

Here is the link for Unicode list (please see the Basic Latin list):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

Open the js file in a text editor and check the encoding.